# Unescape comma when reading CSV with spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV file that contains name field with comma (,) escaped with `\`

```
id,name
"10","Ashraful\, Islam"
```

I am reading the csv file from pyspark

```
test = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ",").option("escape", "\\").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load("test.csv")
test.show()
```

The name should be `Ashraful, Islam`, but getting output

```
+---+----------------+
| id|            name|
+---+----------------+
| 10|Ashraful\, Islam|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: In the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/34c4b9c57e114cdb390e4dbc7383284d82fea317/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py#L359) it says *"escape: sets a single character used for escaping quotes inside an already quoted value. If None is set, it uses the default value, `\ `."* - Try removing the `escape` option.

Comment: @Tomalak I also tried without escape option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
df = spark.read.csv('file:///mypath.../myFile.csv', sep=',', header=True)       
df.show()
```

This gives the output:

```
+---+---------------+
| id|           name|
+---+---------------+
| 10|Ashraful, Islam|
+---+---------------+
```

**EDIT**: I could not replicate your problem with the input file you have but if it persists you can solve it with a workaround. Simply replace "\," (or any other special character which is escaped) in the dataframe.

You can

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.csv('file:///home/perfman/todel.csv', sep=',', header=True)
df.withColumn('nameClean', regexp_replace('name', '\\\,', ',')).show()

>>>
+---+----------------+---------------+
| id|            name|      nameClean|
+---+----------------+---------------+
| 10|Ashraful\, Islam|Ashraful, Islam|
+---+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Still getting `Ashraful\, Islam`. with `spark.read.csv('file:///mypath.../myFile.csv', sep=',', header=True)`

I am using spark 2.3.0 with python 2.7.5

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I think I know what's going on. Escaping commas is not necessary when the value is in quotes. That's what quotes are for. Therefore the CSV reader interprets the backslash as an *actual* backslash. To test this hypothesis, try to importing `10,Ashraful\, Islam` and `10,"Ashraful, Islam"`. If I'm correct then both should look fine.

Comment: @Tomalak I know In csv when a string is enclose with quote, it doesn't required to escape `,`. But my input csv is coming from  another system that we can't change. That's why I want to unescape it from my side

Comment: I tested it in Spark 2.1 with python 2.7.5 also so this is weird. Commas do not need to be escaped in csv when in quotes. If it does not work maybe you can try to replace all \, with , in the input file before you read it as a data frame

Comment: Reading the documentation again (see first comment on the question) it says *"used for escaping quotes inside an already quoted value"*, so it will only look at `\"` and not at anything else. `\,` is taken literally. I agree, replacing `\,` with `,` is the way to go.